# What does LINQ query .Where() do?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a linq query which I'm not able to understand, what does it do ?

```cs
@Model.MenuItems.Where(t=>t.Category.Name.Equals(category.Name))
```

Comment: Collection `MenuItems` is being filtered based on specified `category.Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Find the items from the model's property "MenuItems" that has a category name equal to category.name"

It is like a filter on the list MenuItems

Comment: it is filtering but how

Comment: what does .Equals(category.Name) do

Comment: .Equals(cateogry.name) translates to  "== category.Name"

Comment: @MatJ this has nothing to do with Entity btw, its pure Linq ( not the same thing )

Comment: aah, yes my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering MenuItems by the catergory.Name

Answer (score 0):

The collection MenuItems is being filtered (WHERE) by it's associated Category (Category.Name). The Category is in a separate table (Category or Categories) and linked by a Foreign Key. The Category table has a column Name. The table structure is most likely similar to this:

```
    TABLE [MenuItem] (
      [MenuItemId],
      [Name],
      [CategoryId]
    )

    TABLE [Category] (
      [CategoryId],
      [Name],
    )
```

There is also an assumption, the Category Foreign Key is required (not null) and Name is required and not null. If they are nullable, the above query may throw null exceptions.

In the background, Entity Framework is generating the equivalent SQL query and automatically mapping the results to the models.

.Equals determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: what does .Equals(category.Name) do

Comment: well, it checks if object is equal to another ... guess what - that's why it has such name

Comment: `Determines whether the specified object is equal to the current object.`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Collection of Menu-items is filtered based on category.name.